# Doctrine second level result caching not working with deep fetch join query

Tags: php, mysql, caching, doctrine-orm, dql

I have the following query in a doctrine repository:

```
/**
 * @return AbstractSurveyPage[]
 */
public function getResultCacheTestPages(): array
{
    $select = $this->createQueryBuilder('page')
        ->select(['page', 'pageGroup', 'groupLabelText'])
        ->leftJoin('page.group', 'pageGroup')
        ->leftJoin('pageGroup.labelText', 'groupLabelText');

    // Both useResultCache(true) and setCacheable(true) is needed
    return $select->getQuery()->useResultCache(true)
                  ->setCacheable(true)->getResult();
}
```

The query fetches page objects, their group objects and the group label eagerly.

However, I get the following error:

> File /home/vagrant/web-projects/blueprint/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Cache/DefaultQueryCache.php:263
>   Message Undefined index: labelText

It seems that doctrine cannot find the labelText association of the group object. When I remove `'groupLabelText'` from the select clause, the query and the second level result caching work fine (but the group label objects are not fetched eagerly anymore). When I disable caching with `setCacheable(false)`, the query works fine.

It seems that doctrine is unable to cache results of fetch join queries with joins of more than one level.

Is there a way to get this working? Or should I not use deep fetch join queries, and use lazy fetching for the joined objects? Entity and association second level caching works fine for me, so maybe the performance hit is not that bad. Also, the code would become easier, since the fetch join queries are quite complicated (I use up to 25 joins and elements in the select clause in real code).